# AWS Ansible iterate through several regions and share AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I created an Ansible playbook to search for a certain AMI Name in different regions:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - ec2_ami_find:
      region: "{{ item }}"
      owner: "self"
      name: "*ami-name*"
      sort: creationDate
      sort_order: descending
      sort_end: 1
      no_result_action: fail
    register: ami_result
    with_items: "{{ regions }}"
```

With the debug option:

```
- debug: var=ami_result.results
```

I'm getting the following output (excerpt):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ami_result.results": [
        {
            "item": "us-east-1", 
            "results": [
                {
                    "ami_id": "ami-6b0e727c", 
                }
            ]
        }, 
            "item": "eu-west-1", 
            "results": [
                {
                    "ami_id": "ami-c91e66ba"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I iterate through the items and results for the different regions to share the AMI with others using the `ec2_ami` Ansible module?

For a single region I'd access the `ami_id` like this:

```
image: "{{ ami_result.results[0].ami_id }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way with Ansible 2.1+ and [loop_control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control)

First, there's a `find_ami.yml`

```
- ec2_ami_find:
    region: "{{ outer_item }}"
    owner: "self"
    name: "ami-name"
    sort: creationDate
    sort_order: descending
    sort_end: 1
    no_result_action: fail
  register: ami_result

- ec2_ami:
    region: "{{ outer_item }}"
    image_id: "{{ ami_result.results[0].ami_id }}"
    launch_permissions:
      user_ids: ['1234567890']
```

and a `share_ami.yml`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include: find_ami.yml
    with_items: "{{regions}}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: outer_item
```

The regions are stored in `group_vars/all`